# Exercise 3.F.28 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, dual-spaces

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

I solved Exercise 3.F.28.
This exercise is very abstract for me.
So, I am not sure that my solution is ok or not.

> 3.94 **Definition** ***dual space***, $V'$
> The ***dual space*** of $V$, denoted $V'$, is the vector space of all linear functionals on $V$. In other words, $V'=\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$.

> 3.99 **Definition** ***dual map***, $T'$
> If $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$, then the ***dual map*** of $T$ is the linear map $T'\in\mathcal{L}(W',V')$ defined by $T'(\varphi)=\varphi\circ T$ for $\varphi\in W'.$

> Exercise 3.F.28
> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and there exists $\varphi\in W'$ such that $\operatorname{null}T'=\operatorname{span}(\varphi).$ Prove that $\operatorname{range}T=\operatorname{null}\varphi.$

I used the following proposition on p.107 in this book:

> 3.109 **The range of $T'$**
> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W).$ Then
> (a) $\dim\operatorname{range}T'=\dim\operatorname{range}T;$

> My solution:
> Assume that $\varphi=0$.
> Then, $\operatorname{null}\varphi=W.$
> Then, $\operatorname{null}T'=\operatorname{span}(\varphi)=\{0\}$.
> By Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps (3.22 on p.63),
> $\dim W'=\dim\operatorname{null}T'+\dim\operatorname{range}T'=\dim\operatorname{range}T'.$
> Since $\dim W'=\dim W$ and $\dim\operatorname{range}T'=\dim\operatorname{range}T$ by 3.109,
> $\dim W=\dim\operatorname{range}T.$
> So, $\operatorname{range}T=W=\operatorname{null}\varphi.$
> Assume that $\varphi\neq 0$.
> Then, $\dim\operatorname{null}T'=\dim\operatorname{span}(\varphi)=1.$
> By Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps (3.22 on p.63),  $\dim W'=\dim\operatorname{null}T'+\dim\operatorname{range}T'=1+\dim\operatorname{range}T'.$
> Since $\varphi\neq 0$, $\dim\operatorname{range}\varphi=1.$
> By Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps (3.22 on p.63),
> $\dim W=\dim\operatorname{null}\varphi+\dim\operatorname{range}\varphi=\dim\operatorname{null}\varphi+1.$
> Since $\dim W'=\dim W$,
> $\dim\operatorname{range}T'=\dim\operatorname{null}\varphi.$
> By 3.109,
> $\dim\operatorname{range}T=\dim\operatorname{null}\varphi.$
> Since $\varphi\in\operatorname{span}(\varphi)=\operatorname{null}T'$,
> $T'(\varphi)=\varphi\circ T=0$.
> So, $\operatorname{range}T\subset\operatorname{null}\varphi.$
> Since $\dim\operatorname{range}T=\dim\operatorname{null}\varphi$,
> $\operatorname{range}T=\operatorname{null}\varphi.$

Comment: I've noticed that every day you're posting your solutions from LADR, and asking for feedback. If you're interested, the website https://linearalgebras.com has solutions for most of the problems from this text, and one thing you could do is check your answers against theirs before asking for feedback here.

Comment: @ElliotHerrington Thank you very much for your information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did the same problem, did the same solution, seems good to me. (Sorry for the late response).

Comment: Fabrizio Gambelin, Thank you very much for your answer.